# Fetch value from XML Object?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, xpath-2.0

I need to fetch the value of "joinmeetingurl" element from the xml. I tried in following way. But it returns nothing. Please help me to fetch the value.

```
<?php 

$xml = '<serv:message xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service"
        xmlns:com="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/common"
        xmlns:meet="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/meeting"
        xmlns:att="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/attendee">
          <serv:header>
            <serv:response>
              <serv:result>SUCCESS</serv:result>
                <serv:gsbstatus>PRIMARY</serv:gsbstatus>
            </serv:response>
          </serv:header>
          <serv:body>
            <serv:bodycontent xsi:type="meet:getjoinurlMeetingResponse"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <meet:joinmeetingurl>meetingURL</meet:joinmeetingurl>
           </serv:bodycontent>
        </serv:body>
       </serv:message>';

  $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
  $items = $xml->registerXPathNamespace('meet','http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/meeting');

  $resp = $xml->xpath('//meet:joinmeetingurl');

?>
```

Im getting empty value for $resp always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath should've worked, and you can cast the element to `string` to get the value, for example :

```
$xml = <<<XML
<serv:message xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service"
        xmlns:com="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/common"
        xmlns:meet="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/meeting"
        xmlns:att="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/attendee">
          <serv:header>
            <serv:response>
              <serv:result>SUCCESS</serv:result>
                <serv:gsbstatus>PRIMARY</serv:gsbstatus>
            </serv:response>
          </serv:header>
          <serv:body>
            <serv:bodycontent xsi:type="meet:getjoinurlMeetingResponse"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <meet:joinmeetingurl>meetingURL</meet:joinmeetingurl>
           </serv:bodycontent>
        </serv:body>
       </serv:message>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('meet','http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/meeting');
$resp = $xml->xpath('//meet:joinmeetingurl');
echo (string)$resp[0];
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/488602)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
meetingURL
```

Answer (score 0):

Can offer no guidance with `simplexml` and associated functions but it seems quite simple with standard `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`

```
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );

$xpath=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xpath->query('//meet:joinmeetingurl');
foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->nodeValue;
$dom=null;
```